# Why doesn't this function accept a row vector as an argument? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

For an assignment in a MATLAB course that I'm taking, the assignment called for creating a function that would find a Saddle point in a matrix (a point that has the highest value in its row, and lowest value in its column).  I had the following code initially:

```
function indices = saddle(M)
%  saddle point element who value >= to everything it in its row, and <= every element in its column
% indicies has two columns,  each row of indicies corresponds to saddle point 


indices = [];
a = min(M);  
b = max(M'); 

for xx =  1:size(M,1)
    for yy = 1:size(M,2)
        if M(xx,yy) == a(yy) && M(xx,yy) == b(xx)
            indices = [indices; xx, yy] ;  
            
        end
    end
end
end
```

This would work for any matrix that wasn't a single row vector.

I ended up getting around it with this code:

```
function indices = saddle(M)
%  saddle point element who value >= to everything it in its row, and <= every element in its column
% indicies has two columns,  each row of indicies corresponds to saddle point 

isVector = (size(M,1) == 1 && size(M,2) > 1);

indices = [];
a = min(M);  
b = max(M'); 

for xx =  1:size(M,1)
    for yy = 1:size(M,2)
        if isVector == 0
            if M(xx,yy) == a(yy) && M(xx,yy) == b(xx)
                indices = [indices; xx, yy] ;  
            end  
        else
            if M(1, yy) == max(M)
                indices = [indicies; 1, yy];
            end
        end
    end
end

end
```

However I'm just confused as to why the initial code wouldn't work.  It would work with scalers, it would work with a n*1 vectors, it would work with anything except row vectors.

Also any tips on a better way to attack this problem, or ways to clean up the code is much appreciated.  Just learning MATLAB and was happy I was able to figure out a working solution, but I'm always looking for some ways to get better.   Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`min` and `max` will return scalar values, not one value per row/column, if you pass them 1-D arrays. You need to specify the dimensions if you don't want that to happen, e.g.

```
a = min(M,[],1);  
b = max(M,[],2); % = max(M.',[],1).'
```